# How to permanently disable javadsl namespace when coding with Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have started to learn Akka Streams. One of my very very big annoyances of the product is that almost all classes appear in both `javadsl` and `scaladsl` namespaces.

Somehow, IntelliJ will automatically import classes from javadsl namespace first. This leads to syntax errors and a lot of wasted time. Problems disappear when I import the same class from the scaladsl namespace.

How can I block/hide the javadsl namespace permanently? perhaps there is some setting in SBT so that when I import the akka streams dependency, I tell SBT to kill the visibility to the javadsl namespace.

Or maybe some other solution which prevents IntelliJ from automatically importing classes from javadsl namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: Settings]

Just add `akka.stream.javadsl` there, and it should stop suggesting items from the `javadsl` package.